# site. master header is missing while compiling asp site through iis7

Tags: asp.net

I am running a asp site on iis 7 , recently I made some changes in site master page regarding header and footer. 
When I compile my site through visual studio than its perfect bit through iis7 my header and footer are missing. 
Although my site works perfectly fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is the site hosted in your local system?

Comment: Reason could be the `css` or the closing of the `html-tags` are not proper. So put your `CSS` and `HTML` in you question for better understanding of your question.